# Automatize VBA Excel maco

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not very good at this, so I used to add these rules manually, because those was working only for cells that are filled.

Any way to automatize this? Thanks.

```
Range("D22:G22").Select

    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D22:G23"), Type:=xlFillDefault

    Range("D22:G23").Select

    Range("I22").Select

    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("I22:I23"), Type:=xlFillDefault

    Range("I22:I23").Select

    Range("M22:N22").Select

    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M22:N23"), Type:=xlFillDefault

    Range("M22:N23").Select

    Sheets("BN1").Select

    Range("C20:G20").Select

    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C20:G21"), Type:=xlFillDefault

    Range("C20:G21").Select

    Range("K20:L20").Select

    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("K20:L21"), Type:=xlFillDefault

    Range("K20:L21").Select

    Sheets("BUM1").Select

    Range("C20:G20").Select

    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C20:G21"), Type:=xlFillDefault

    Range("C20:G21").Select

    Range("K20:L20").Select

    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("K20:L21"), Type:=xlFillDefault

    Range("K20:L21").Select

    Sheets("Express").Select

    Range("C20:G20").Select

    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C20:G21"), Type:=xlFillDefault

    Range("C20:G21").Select

    Range("K20:L20").Select

    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("K20:L21"), Type:=xlFillDefault

    Range("K20:L21").Select

    Sheets("DL1").Select

    Range("C20:G20").Select

    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C20:G21"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Comment: what did you want to do? what are your inputs? expected outputs?

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing that you recorded the above code with the macro recorder.  The macro recorder is great for discovering the syntax of obscure commands but it can be difficult to tidy its output.

Consider your last few statements.

```
Sheets("Express").Select
Range("C20:G20").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C20:G21"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("C20:G21").Select
Range("K20:L20").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("K20:L21"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("K20:L21").Select
Sheets("DL1").Select
Range("C20:G20").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C20:G21"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

I can replace these statements with:

```
With Sheets("Express")
  .Range("C20:G20").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("C20:G21"), Type:=xlFillDefault
  .Range("K20:L20").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("K20:L21"), Type:=xlFillDefault
End With
With Sheets("DL1")
  .Range("C20:G20").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("C20:G21"), Type:=xlFillDefault
End With
```

which I think you will agree looks tidier but needs a little explanation.

Consider:

```
With Sheets("Express")
  .Range("C20:G20").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("C20:G21"), Type:=xlFillDefault
  .Range("K20:L20").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("K20:L21"), Type:=xlFillDefault
End With
```

The `With` says I want Sheets("Express") added to the front of anything that starts with a dot until the `End With`.

So these four lines are exactly the same as:

```
  Sheets("Express").Range("C20:G20").AutoFill Destination:=Sheets("Express").Range("C20:G21"), Type:=xlFillDefault
  Sheets("Express").Range("K20:L20").AutoFill Destination:=Sheets("Express").Range("K20:L21"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Consider:

```
Sheets("Express").Select
Range("C20:G20").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C20:G21"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("C20:G21").Select
```

The macro recorder has recorded each step as you performed it.  You switched to worksheet "Express", you selected range C20:G20 and then copies that range down a row.

It is better not to select anything if you can avoid it because it slows your macro down and usually make the code harder to understand.

The syntax of the AutoFill method is:

*SourceRange*.AutoFill Destination:=*DestinationRange*, Type:=*Type*

So it is possible to include all the parameters in a single line as I have.

Consider:

```
Type:=xlFillDefault
```

The macro recorder has set the type to `xlFillDefault` which tells the compiler to make a guess of the type of fill required by looking at the source data.  Look up AutoFill in VB Help and you will get a list of all the types of fill.  Pick the one you want.

**Summary**

Is this the level of detail you were seeking?  Come back with more questions if necessary.

Comment: Another systematic and thorough answer!  +1

Comment: I need to apply those rules for entire columns. Now they are for one row and selected columns.
Thanks!

Comment: I suspected from the title of your question that you wanted more.  In your question all the copies are from a range of columns on a single row to the next row.  Now you say you want entire columns.  Do you mean you want to copy column C to column D?  Do you want a routine that will accept C and D as parameters?  Neither of these changes is difficult but you need to explain what you seek.